# Find IP repetitions in a list of IPs

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of IP addresses and I would like a regex that matches the ranges (`xx.xxx.xx.`) that are repeated at least 5 times.

Example
The list:

```
12.15.56.231 
12.15.168.243
12.16.168.6
12.18.144.244
12.18.149.231
12.86.149.231 
12.81.196.7
12.81.196.8 
12.81.196.13
12.8.24.8 
12.8.24.10
12.8.24.12
12.8.24.13 
12.8.24.18
12.8.24.21
12.8.27.5 
12.8.27.231
```

In that case, it should return:

```
12.8.24.8 
12.8.24.10
12.8.24.12
12.8.24.13 
12.8.24.18
12.8.24.21
```

I'm still new to using regex, I've tried several things, the closest I got was this:

```
(([\d]{1,3}.)([\d]{1,3}.)([\d]{1,3}.)){5,}
```

Comment: Does it have to be regex?

Comment: Preferably, but not necessarily

Answer (score 1):

Not a regex solution, but you can use `collections.Counter` creatively to accomplish this:

```py
import collections

text = """12.15.56.231 
12.15.168.243
12.16.168.6
12.18.144.244
12.18.149.231
12.86.149.231 
12.81.196.7
12.81.196.8 
12.81.196.13
12.8.24.8 
12.8.24.10
12.8.24.12
12.8.24.13 
12.8.24.18
12.8.24.21
12.8.27.5 
12.8.27.231"""

ip_addresses = text.splitlines()
counts = collections.Counter(".".join(k.split(".")[:3]) for k in ip_addresses)
print([ip for c in counts if counts[c] > 4 for ip in ip_addresses if ip.startswith(c)])
```

this will print:

```
['12.8.24.8 ', '12.8.24.10', '12.8.24.12', '12.8.24.13 ', '12.8.24.18', '12.8.24.21']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll wait if any solution appears using regex, otherwise I'll use your solution.

Comment: No worries. The upside of this method is that your list doesn't have to be sorted.